# Program with no sizing options for windows

Tags: window, size

I have a program that i use for work. cant say what it was, but it was originally written in dos and seems like they just added a GUI to it. The main program window does not even have a minimize maximize or X button in the top right.

When using the software if opens a sub window within the main window, not a popup window. and its a set height and width despite multiple pages of it having a scroll bar and all the wasted space around it.

any thoughts on how i can resize this window?

Comment: The answers here are a little facetious: DOS applications frequently used what is now called a "text-based user interface" which *looks graphical* to modern users. They used ANSI text codes to render graphical areas and blocks and frequently presented "popup child windows" as overlays. See: Norton Commander etc. Since they were text-based and full-screen there was usually a fixed column and row count. This is why they do not resize. The answers are correct that you cannot really do anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "just add a GUI" to DOS.  Not even in the Win95 days when this was closer to being possible.

The ability to minimize, maximize, or 'X' is controlled by the application itself when it creates the window.  One of the options is to skip this part and draw the whole thing within the application itself (or no bar at all).

Yes, it is true that *usually* a programmer just uses a system default titlebar when creating a window but there are no rules requiring them to do so.

You might be able to hack the code resource file of the exe if it is using a dialog structure but the question itself makes me think that you have a long journey ahead as only a Windows programmer understands the flags used for window creation.

A programmer can (and often does) create an entire window using code and not a dialog structure.  This makes the hack that much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

[As said by Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/a/1703871/1219498), [One does not simply "Add GUI to dos"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDmp8.jpg), and, the conventional titlebar isn't a necessity. 
Usually programmers give the window a fixed size when their program may not render properly/clearly when window is resized. Even if you do resize it, you'll have a good time with overlapping objects and containers.

An internet research led me to this app: http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/ That claims it can help you. Although I have no experience how this app works...

As for minimising/maximizing window, you can use the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> menu. I know it's still not as convinient as the top-right buttons, but its still improvement.

Comment: Dude.  I love the meme. :D  You made my night.